# white space in xslt

Tags: c#, whitespace

I'm trying to generate a report which contains some white spaces to make the content looks good. but the problem is for some reason the number of spaces is being fixed or even reduced in some cases.

for example I've got a content which should look like this:

Formatted text [image: 1]

but it looks like this

Not formatted text [image: 2]

and the xslt block look like this:

```
<fo:block   white-space-collapse="false"  usage-context-of-suppress-at-line-break="ignore">
                          <xsl:variable name="report_text">
                            <value>
                              <xsl:value-of select="REPORT_TEXT" />
                            </value>
                          </xsl:variable>

                          <xsl:value-of select="DataConvertObject:ConvertToPlainText($report_text)" /> 
</fo:block>
```

any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: Adding [<xsl:preserve-space>](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_preserve-space.asp) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

the problem was each alphabet with the font that I've chosen was in different size so I've changed the font like this:

```
 <fo:table-cell column-number="2" number-columns-spanned="5"  font-family="Lucida Console"  >
```

and it works fine